# Would there be less load on a NAT firewall if some or all of the traffic were routed over IPV6 Instead of IPV4?

Tags: firewall, nat, ipv6

Just curious..  I was thinking that, on a NAT firewall that is normally overloaded, offloading some or all of the IPV4 traffic to IPV6 might make a performance difference?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what makes you think that? Ie, what mechanism would reduce the load? Do you mean load on bandwidth, or CPU, or RAM? What model firewall are you dealing with?

Comment: You could say that... Since NAT is not necessary in IPv6 world. There are enough ipv6 addresses available to give all ip enabled devices in the world their own unique ipv6 address many times over. Something in the neighbourhood of enough addresses to assign each grain of sand on the entire planet ... You should only focus on which ip addresses on LAN can be accessed and which ports should be open in the firewall.

Comment: mfinni - Sorry, I should have stated in my post that my reasoning is that IPV6 does not require NAT at all.. No need to do NAT to me would imply a performance improvement of some kind.  The firewall I am using is not taxed, so I'm not asking this out of a need of any kind, I was just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

NAT can cause issues in a NAT firewall multiple ways. It would put a slightly lower load on the router CPU to ipv6 instead, although NAT is fairly lightweight and it likely don't make a big difference to the CPU.

What is more relevant - and likely the cause of many issues is the size and number of entries.in the connection tracking table - is the mappings between lots of internal addresses and lots of external addresses.   Especially in cases where you have.multiple internal sites hitting few external sites or using complex protocols. This is what tends to cause pain in NAT firewalls, and the ability to handle this at scale is the difference between regular NAT and Carrier Grade NAT.  By moving to IPV6, you eliminate this issue.